# Speed Queen dryer: electrical problem, can not get heat

Tags: dryer

My Speed Queen dryer does not heat up, so yesterday I replaced the temperature sensor on the coil.

I can now read a voltage through the coil with 1 wire unhooked: 120V to ground, 240V on both power wires, but when I connect the wire to the coil, it reads no voltage. What's going wrong here?

Comment: I will take a swag and say it is an open coil (heating element). Post a small sketch of how it is wired and how you took your measurements.

Comment: i unhooked 1 wire from coil turned dryer on and had 120 v to both wires and could read 120 v through the coil from wire that was still connected had 240 v checking both hot wires but connect the loose wire and check from both ends of coil and it doesn't show voltage it's got me stumped

Comment: Show how it is wired and how you took the measurements and what did you use to measure the voltage. Also put both wires on and measure the coil, you should get 240. If not check if you have 240 at the plug with the dryer on. Also is it on a breaker or fuse? Is the dryer on a circuit by itself?

Comment: Power off: Remove both wires and check the resistance of the coil end-to-end...

Comment: both wires unhooked from coil resistance varied 3.6 - 4.3

Comment: i used cen-tec meter removed both wires from coil checkd each to ground and had120 v , i thenchecked both hot wires black to one and red to the other and had 240 v then i connected one to coil and checked other end of coil that did not have wire connected red meter lead to coil black to ground had 120 v accross coil but connected both wires to coil and did not have any voltage . dryer was running during all of these test , i don't know how to show a diagram sorry about that

Comment: Ghost or Phantom Voltage, it goes away as soon you put load on it. Put a light bulb individually on each 120 V (not 240V) wires and see.

Comment: @BradleyScarberry I've edited your post so it's easier to understand. Does my edit still accurately reflect your issue?

Comment: And it might help if you add the specific model of Speed Queen dryer. There should be an ID tag on the machine somewhere (usually on the back, sometimes on the inside of the lid cover).

Comment: dryer is alliance speedqueen  AES17AWF

Comment: i have a coil on order illl try that

Comment: new coil assembly with both sensors lined it out , thank you guys so much for helping me with this